# Android : refresh fragment with dynamic list using ViewPager and ActionbarTab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I'm quite new to Android. I'm stuck with this issue for a few days now.
I'm using the new google's Template of Action bar Tab with swipe (ViewPager).
Inside each fragment, I want to display a dynamic list of cards (with cardslib : https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib). The data for the cards come from an asyncTask which is fetching data from an url.

This is my problem : When I launch the app, the first View is display, but the ViewPager prepare the view for the second page, so the async task for the second screen is launch too. And the cards of the second screen are added to the first one.
Then if i swipe to the second screen, nothing is displayed, and the async task for the third screen is launch. So if swipe to the thrid screen, nothing... And then if i switch again to the second screen, the cards with data of the first screen are displayed... A real mess !

I think I have a probleme with the onCreate, onCreateView, or something like that. Maybe the code is sometimes not at the right place.. I don't know. I tried a lot of small modofication, but nothing worked. (but it worked like this with just action bar tab and without the ViewPager).

Thanks

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
 * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);


//mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    if(tab.getPosition() != mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }
//      mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
//           getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

And here is the Fragment

```
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.Card;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardArrayAdapter;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.internal.CardHeader;
import it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.example.webanajones.asyncTask.GetItemTask;
import com.example.webanajones.asyncTask.IResultsListener;
import com.example.webanajones.asyncTaskResponse.ItemJsonResponse;
import com.example.webanajones.asyncTaskResponse.ItemJsonResponse.Item;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements
        IResultsListener {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static int limit = 0;
    IResultsListener listener = this;
    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter;
    int flag = 0;
    boolean loadMore = true;
    CardListView listView;
    private int idx;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      Bundle data = getArguments();
//      idx = data.getInt("idx") +1;

        limit = 0;
        flag = 0;
        loadMore = true;

        List<String> params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        params.add(String.valueOf(limit));
        GetItemTask getItemTask = new GetItemTask();
        getItemTask.setOnResultsListener(listener);
        getItemTask.execute(params);

    }


    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onGetItemTaskSucceeded(ItemJsonResponse itemJsonResponse) {
        if (mCardArrayAdapter != null) {
            mCardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

        }

        if (itemJsonResponse.getSuccess() != 0) {

            loadMore = true;
            final Item[] itemTable = itemJsonResponse.getItemArray();

            for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemTable.length; itemIndex++) {

                if (itemTable[itemIndex].getTypeId() == 2) { // 2 = type GIF
                    final int index = itemIndex;
                    Card gifCard = new CardGif(getActivity()){


                        @Override
                        public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {
                            DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                            int width = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.97);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            params.bottomMargin = 30;
                            LinearLayout LinearLayout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.inner_frame);

                            GIFWebView gifView = new GIFWebView (getActivity(), itemTable[index].getObjectUrl());

                            LinearLayout.addView(gifView);


                        }
                    }; 
                    CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getActivity());
                    header.setTitle(itemTable[itemIndex].getTitle());
                    cards.add(gifCard);
                }

                if (itemTable[itemIndex].getTypeId() == 1) { // 1 = image
                    Card card = new Card(getActivity());
                    CardHeader header = new CardHeader(getActivity());
                    header.setTitle(itemTable[itemIndex].getTitle());
                    card.addCardHeader(header);
                    MyThumbnail thumb = new MyThumbnail(getActivity(), itemTable[itemIndex].getObjectUrl());
                    thumb.setExternalUsage(true);

                    card.addCardThumbnail(thumb);
                    final int index = itemIndex;
                    card.addPartialOnClickListener(Card.CLICK_LISTENER_THUMBNAIL_VIEW, new Card.OnCardClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(Card card, View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FullscreenActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("imageUrl", itemTable[index].getObjectUrl());
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    cards.add(card);
                }

            }
            if (flag == 0) {
                mCardArrayAdapter = new CardArrayAdapter(getActivity(), cards);
                listView = (CardListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                        R.id.carddemo_list);
                listView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);

                flag = 1;
            }               
        } 
        else {
            loadMore = false;
        }
        loadMoreCards(mCardArrayAdapter, loadMore);

    }

    public void loadMoreCards(CardArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter, boolean loadMore) {


        if (listView != null) {
            mCardArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

            if (loadMore) {
                listView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                        limit += 5;
                        List<String> params = new ArrayList();
                        params.add("1");
                        params.add(String.valueOf(limit));          
                        GetItemTask getItemTask = new GetItemTask();
                        getItemTask.setOnResultsListener(listener);
                        getItemTask.execute(params);


                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
//fin placeholderfrag

    @Override
    public void onGetImageTaskSucceeded(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here:https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/issues/85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @GabrieleMariotti, it helped ! In fact I already tried to use different classes for the different fragments, but I forget to give diferent IDs to my cardsLists. It solved the problem. Btw, good job for your lib, it is awesome.

So for the next one : create differents classes for all your differents fragments. They have to use differents layout, and the cardsList have to use differents ID.